# Python - configparser if statement and edit the data in .ini file

Tags: python, ini, configparser

How can I edit data with an if statement if the data is equal to an example?

```py
if DisplayMenu == "1":
        config = ConfigParser()
        if config["SETTINGS"] == {"Tutorial": "True"}:
            config["SETTINGS"] = {
                "Tutorial": "False"
                }
        if config["SETTINGS"] == {"Tutorial": "False"}:
            config["SETTINGS"] = {
                "Tutorial": "True"
                }
```

What I want to do is when in the settings tab the value tutorial is equal to true then change to false and vice versa. How to do this? I get an error using this

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\Immortal Conquest\Main\Settings.py", line 80, in <module>
    DisplayMenu()
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\Desktop\Immortal Conquest\Main\Settings.py", line 27, in DisplayMenu
    print("[1] Tutorial  = " + config['SETTINGS']['Tutorial'])
  File "C:\Users\Stagiair\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'SETTINGS'
```

Code I use to Create .ini file

```py
#Makes a Settingsfile
def CreateSettingsFile():
    try:
        import os, sys, time, pickle, colorama, threading, ctypes
        from configparser import ConfigParser
    except Exception as e:
        print("Some modules are mssing! Install them and try again! {}".format(e))
    os.system("cls")
    #Get the configparser object
    config = ConfigParser()

    #Assume we need 2 sections in the config file, let's call them SETTINGS and USERINFO
    config["SETTINGS"] = {
        "Music": "True",
        "Tutorial": "True",
        "GameSaves": "True"
    }
    config["USERINFO"] = {
        "username": "Not Set"
    }
    config["GAMEITEMS"] = {
        "EXP": "None",
        "Items" : "None",
        "Kills" : "None",
        "Saved" : "None"
    }
    #Write the above sections to config.ini file
    with open('GameSaves/config.ini', 'w') as conf:
        config.write(conf)
    os.system("cls")
```